# Tikz: Calculate position based on node using fit option

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I want the nodes `c` and `d` be inside `q` and the position of `q` to be determined by `p`.

A second problem is, that the distance between `p` and `q` isn't correct even with `on grid=false` (I guess the width of `p` isn't available because of using `fit`?).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) [draw=black] {a};
\node (b) [draw=black,on grid,below=of a] {long text};
\node (p) [draw=black,fit={(a) (b)}] {};

\node (c) [draw=red] {c};
\node (d) [draw=red,below=of c] {d};
\node (q) [right=of p,draw=red,fit={(c) (d)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `matrix`?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=8mm,row sep=3mm] {
\node (a) [draw=black] {a};
&
\node (c) [draw=red] {c};
\\
\node (b) [draw=black] {long text};
&
\node (d) [draw=red] {d};
\\
};
\node (p) [draw=black,fit={(a) (b)}] {};
\node (q) [draw=red,fit={(c) (d)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The advantage of using one matrix (instead of two) is that it also looks good if the vertical dimensions of the nodes vary.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[column sep=8mm,row sep=3mm,anchor=center] (mat) {
\node (a) [draw=black] {a};
&
\node (c) [draw=red] {c};
\\
\node (b) [draw=black,align=center] {long\\ text};
&
\node (d) [draw=red] {d};
\\
};
\node (p) [draw=black,fit={(a) (b) (b|-mat.south)}] {};
\node (q) [draw=red,fit={(c) (d) (d|-mat.south)}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As in any Ti*k*Z matrix, every line, including the last one, has to be terminated by `\\`.

Comment: Maybe you want to call attention to the `\\ ` before the `};`

Answer (score 3):

[marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470733/1952) proposes to use a `matrix`, but I think two matrices are better:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[draw, matrix of nodes, nodes=draw, row sep=3mm] (a) {
a\\
long text\\
};

\matrix[draw=red, matrix of nodes, nodes={draw=red}, 
          right=3mm of a, row sep=3mm] (b) {
c\\
d\vphantom{g}\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about this as well but I was afraid that, if the nodes have different vertical dimensions, this will no longer work.

Comment: What are the advantages of using two matrices?

Comment: Maybe you want to call attention to the `\\ ` before the `};`

Comment: @marmot It's true, but you can always define the desired dimensions or inner nodes.

Comment: Yes, sure. I just wanted to say that I do not necessarily think that " two matrices are better". Either of our two options may be advantageous depending on what you precisely intent to do.

Comment: @ben I just wanted to show that a `matrix` is a node that can be `drawn` on its own. Therefore there's no need for `fit` nodes or commands for drawing borders. About `\\` before `};` on last line it's not a mistake, you should include them. Look at marmots solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 4 mm,
every node/.style = {inner sep=1mm, minimum height=1.5em}
                    ]
\node (a) [draw=black] {a};
\node (b) [draw=black,below=of a] {long text};
\node (p) [draw=black,fit={(a) (b)}] {};

\node (c) [draw=red,right=of b.east |- a] {c};
\node (d) [draw=red,below=of c] {d};
\node (q) [draw=red,fit={(c) (d)}] {};%right=of p,
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not knew `|-`. This is only available because of the `positioning` library, isn't it? But for your solution one has to know if `a` or `b` determines the width of `p`, which isn't perfectly easy, but should work for me

Comment: @Ben No, -| and |- have nothing to do with the positioning library.